# How can I filter all event or meeting responses coming in without extra context in gMail?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar, gmail-filters, email

I am looking for a filter that removes emails automatically from my inbox if they are responses to events and meetings set up in google calendar. I want this to be as smart as possible

- Keeping replies with a note in my inbox
- Keeping replies to an invite (answered emails) in my inbox
- Only affect responses from my company
- Tag the emails and remove them from the inbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I came up with and is currently in testing. Copy and paste this into the "has the words" filter field

`("has accepted this invitation." OR "has declined this invitation." OR "has replied Maybe to this invitation.") AND -("this invitation with this note:" AND -("Declined because I am out of office")) AND -"and proposed a new time" AND "Invitation from Google Calendar" AND -subject:("Re: Tentatively Accepted:" OR "Re: Accepted:" OR "Re: Declined:") AND from:example.com`

### Let's walk through the parts:

#### Finding boring replies

`("has accepted this invitation." OR "has declined this invitation." OR "has replied Maybe to this invitation.")`

This block is looking for the text that appears in the box to the top of the invitation response. This is very general and the next section will go into it in more detail.

#### Not filtering responses with notes.

`AND -("this invitation with this note:" AND -("Declined because I am out of office"))`

I know, the `AND` is optional but it provides some structure. This excludes all responses with a note fro the filter. It also captures the out of office case. This is a note that I can ignore.

#### People that propose new times are actually interesting

`AND -"and proposed a new time"`

If that is in the email, you want to review it definitely.

#### Make sure it's from gCal

`AND "Invitation from Google Calendar"`

The other part is something that is in every Google Calendar Invite. One could also check if an `invite.ics` is attached.

#### Don't filter actual replies to emails where someone hits reply instead of adding a note

`AND -subject:("Re: Tentatively Accepted:" OR "Re: Accepted:" OR "Re: Declined:")`

This part will not (`-subject` for negation) filter those mails that have a `Re: Something` in the subject.

#### Limit this to a small range of senders

`AND from:example.com`

Constrain this only to a single domain (e.g. your company)

### Turning it into a filter for automation

- Follow [Google's help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en) to make this do what you want.
- Copy and paste this into the "has the words" filter field

### Where this could go wrong?

In many places. This is a quick fix and I will expand it. No test driven development. Sorry.